# How to print an inverted pyramid?

Tags: python, loops

These are what I'm currently working with:

```
row = int(input('Enter number of rows required: '))

for i in range(row,0,-1):
    for j in range(row-i):
        print('*', end='') 
    
    for j in range(2*i-1):
        print('0',end='')
    print()
```

And this is the current output:

```
0000000
*00000
**000
***0
```

I can't figure out what to change to have the correct output

Answer (score 2):

Add another asterisk-printing loop before printing a newline.

```
row = 4
for i in range(row, 0, -1):
    for j in range(row - i):
        print('*', end='')

    for j in range(2 * i - 1):
        print('0', end='')

    for j in range(row - i):
        print('*', end='')

    print()
```

prints out

```
0000000
*00000*
**000**
***0***
```

(For a more Pythonic solution, you could just

```
row = 4
full_width = 2 * row - 1
for i in range(row, 0, -1):
    row_zeroes = (2 * i - 1)
    print(("0" * row_zeroes).center(full_width, '*'))
```

but I suspect that's not the point of this exercise.)

Comment: Ooh, `center` is nice. I'd get the zeros directly from a range: `for row_zeroes in range(full_width, -1, -2):` I think that shows more clearly that they start with full width and then decrease by 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can use f-string and siple nth number from the formula `a + (n-1)*d`

```py
row = int(input('Enter number of rows required: '))

for i in range(row):
    print(f'{"*"*(i+1)}{"0"*(2*(row-i-1) - 1)}{"*"*(i+1)}')
```

Comment: Prints an extra asterisk in the last row.

Comment: according to the screenshot given by OP, it was supposed to be like that, it can be solved by `row-i` instead of `row-i-1`